# Android 14 default MTU and related considerations

Tags: gatt, mtu

Has the default MTU changed to 517 bytes in Android 14? If so, this would warrant questions pertaining to hardware, the Bluetooth stack, MTU capabilities and proper usage of the function requestMtu().

~I now understand that the default MTU value (23) has not changed under Android 14. Thank you to all who provided feedback and trust that others will find utility in the commentary.

Comment: Why does this break your Bluetooth device firmware? If it follows the spec, it should be compliant and work correctly.

Comment: Were are using a pre 4.2 BLE module in our peripheral.   These modules do not have the capability of returning a requested MTU (this was back when the only packet size was 23 bytes). As a result, the default Android MTU (517) is persisted.

Comment: Correction:  This would just break pre 4.2 BLE modules without MTU negotiation capabilities (as is the case with our module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you describe in your question, BluetoothGatt offers a [requestMtu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#requestMtu(int)) method since API 21. However, [this is not possible in Android 14 and beyond](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#mtu-set-to-517):

> ### MTU is set to 517 for the first GATT client requesting an MTU
>
> Starting from Android 14, the Android Bluetooth stack more strictly adheres to
> Version 5.2 of the Bluetooth Core Specification and requests the BLE
> ATT MTU to 517 bytes when the first GATT client requests an MTU using
> the BluetoothGatt#requestMtu(int) API, and disregards all subsequent
> MTU requests on that ACL connection.

The workarounds include changing your firmware:

> Your peripheral device should respond to the Android device's MTU
> request with a reasonable value that can be accommodated by the
> peripheral. The final negotiated value will be a minimum of the
> Android requested value and the remote provided value (i.e. `min(517, remoteMtu)`)

...or manually sending appropriately-sized packets:

> - Alternatively, limit your GATT characteristic writes based on the minimum between the known supported value of your peripheral and the received MTU change
>
>   - A reminder that you should reduce 5 bytes from the supported size for the headers
>   - For example: arrayMaxLength = min(SUPPORTED_MTU, GATT_MAX_ATTR_LEN(517)) - 5

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these strategies will work for us as we use a pre 4.2 BLE module in our peripheral.  These modules do not have the capability of returning a requested MTU (this was back when the only packet size was 23 bytes).  Thank you for your answer regardless!

Comment: Correction:  This would just break pre 4.2 BLE modules without MTU negotiation capabilities (as is the case with our module).

Comment: @wsmitty76 That's a shame; do you know what Bluetooth stack you're trying to support? For example, [TI's CC2540](https://www.ti.com/product/CC2540) (BLE 4.0) seems to support [GATT_ExchangeMTU](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru271i/swru271i.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! We are using a similar chip with what seems to be an outdated stack.  MTU exchange is the only requirement.  The specs for that sheet say Bluetooth low energy 5.0?

Comment: @wsmitty76 Funny you should mention that: you'll see on [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/t/texas-instruments/cc2540-bluetooth-system-on-chip) that it was advertised as 4.0 upon release in 2010 ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2540.pdf)), but in [the software developers' guide I linked above](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru271i/swru271i.pdf) section 1.1 (page 8) says that the same hardware qualified for Bluetooth 5.0 as well. I can't find any previous revisions dated before 2020 (5.0) but I don't see any reason to believe MTU exchange is new in 5.0+.

Comment: From what I can see MTU exchange was only introduced in 4.2.  Our particular issue is that we are using an old batch of chips (apparently).  I need to do some sleuthing to determine what the specs were when they were purchased.

Comment: This is the chip we are using: https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/wireless-connectivity/bluetooth/lineup/bluetooth-low-energy/series/90876

Comment: Based on this datasheet: https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/4535 I don't see any evidence that this Bluetooth 4.0 chip ever did MTU negotiation.

Comment: @wsmitty76 MTU exchange was absolutely part of the Bluetooth 4.0 spec (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-4-0/) on p1908 (Vol 3 Part G Sec 4.2 Item 1). The product page you linked shows that your module's "Used ICs" are universally CC2540 or CC2541, and also that you have your choice on a TI stack or BlueRadios stack. Your engineers will know best which stack you're using and how custom your firmware is, but I think it's clear enough to me that the chipset in those modules is capable of MTU exchange despite the modules' age.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in piecing this puzzle together.   From another stackoverflow question I posted it seems that BLE communications should work with Android 14 even without a Bluetooth chip that can do MTU negotiations .... which would make hardware and stack discussions moot.   The documentation for all this is a bit sparse.